# linq to lambda expression

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to convert the code below to a lambda expression

```
from b in bookResults
group b by new { b.Title1, b.Pubs_id, b.Notes } into g
select new XElement("book",
new XAttribute("pub_id", g.Key.Pubs_id), new XAttribute("note", g.Key.Notes),
new XElement("Title", g.Key.Title1),
from bk in g
select new XElement("Name", new XAttribute("au_id", bk.Au_id), bk.Name))));
```

lambda expression

```
bookResults.GroupBy(g => new { g.Title1, g.Pubs_id, g.Notes })
           .Select(group => new XElement("book", 
                                         new XAttribute("pub_id",
                                                        group.Key.Pubs_id),
                                         new XAttribute("note", group.Key.Notes),
                                         new XElement("Title", group.Key.Title1)))
                           **.Select(bk => new XElement("Name",
                                                        new XAttribute("au_id",
                                                                       bk.Au_id),
                                                        bk.Name)**)));
```

My issue is with the second select as I don't know how to associate it with
(from bk in g)

Comment: This is not a lambda expression. This is a LINQ query in method call syntax. A lambda expression is just something like `x => blah`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is just yet another regular query, starting with the lambda parameter of the previous select:

```
bookResults.GroupBy(g => new { g.Title1, g.Pubs_id, g.Notes })
     .Select(group => new XElement("book", 
                 new XAttribute("pub_id", group.Key.Pubs_id),
                 new XAttribute("note", group.Key.Notes),
                 new XElement("Title", group.Key.Title1)),
                 // "from bk in g select" becomes "g.Select(bk =>"
                 // but here you're using group as the parameter name
                 group.Select(bk => new XElement("Name",
                      new XAttribute("au_id", bk.Au_id), bk.Name))));
```